# No choice icon to run on simulator in Xcode

Tags: ios-simulator

I just downloaded a code pack from github. But there is **no choice** to run the app on simulator and I can only choose to run on **iOS device**. Why does this happen? Can I make any change to enable it to run in simulator?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess the reason could be that I haven't register as an apple developer member. Is there any walk around way to solve it so that I can test it on my simulator before I register as a member?

Comment: Please provide the output of 'xcrun simctl list'.  Are you able to launch iOS Simulator.app and boot a simulated device?  What is shown in Xcode's Device Manager?

Comment: That's too long to put it in one comment, above is one part of it. I think there is nothing wrong with my simulator because I can run other apps on my simulator, but some of the ones which were downloaded can't.  For them, there is simply no choice of simulator, it just showed "iOS Device".

Comment: you should edit your original post with the requested information rather than spamming comments without formatting ;)

Comment: You have simulated devices available as reported by that output.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by "no choice"?  Where are you seeing no choice?

Comment: Oh sorry about that! I just begin my learning of Swift and it was my first time to post a question. I mean normally I can choose the device on the up left corner in Xcode, just beside the icon "run" and "stop", but in the downloaded app, I click on it but there is no drug-down column to choose other devices. It just show "iOS device".

Comment: Hmm... they should certainly be there based on your simctl list output.  Xcode can have issues communicating with the simulator service if Xcode is renamed after launching, and sometimes on the very first time it is launched.  To rule those issues out, does it work as expected if you reboot?

Comment: I tried rebooting Xcode, and I tried some other resetting method using the terminal. The file still didn't show other icons to choose different devices. Since I can actually run other apps in my simulator, and for some apps I downloaded I couldn't, I guess it is not the problem of my settings?

Comment: What do you mean "for some apps I downloaded"?  How are you downloading apps?  Also, I didn't say you should "reboot Xcode".  You should reboot *your computer*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I walked around and didn't use the app I downloaded from github in the end. Can you post an answer and maybe I can accept it? But thanks anyway!